# PHP's fnmatch() discouraged because not available on non-POSIX compliant OS's?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

Some security tools like https://github.com/FloeDesignTechnologies/phpcs-security-audit are showing warnings that this function is discouraged to use because it's not available on all systems. Only thing that I could find was the warning on documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php:
*For now, this function is not available on non-POSIX compliant systems except Windows.*

What to you think how seriously this warning should be taken? How likely it is possible to land on non-POSIX systems these days (developing Drupal CMS)?

Comment: what is you OS? do you want to serve the websie on windows server?

Comment: I have 2 OS's Mac and Linux. We never use Windows for server.